# How to decipher network certification report

Tags: networking

I'm wondering if I can get some tips on deciphering my network certification report, and what would be some "next steps" to get the network to pass.

I'm the person in charge of this network, but I'm not totally up to speed on how to fix the items in the report.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4fltyebg9ltwxn/Rock%20Pointe%20Bearspaw.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a cabling certification report. The failing cables do not meet the tolerances for certification. The practical impact is that the cables may not reliably work when connected to computers and switches. You may see errors, slow speed, unreliable connections, etc, when using these failing cables.

Since you don't have familiarity with cabling standards your best bet is probably to have a cabling contractor come in and re-terminate the failing drops or, if necessary, re-run the wires. An experienced contractor (properly trained and industry certified) can look at that certification report and decide what the best course of action is.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was thinking that might be what I need to do. Based on that report, does it look like re-termination would be sufficient, or is re-cabling needed for anything?

Comment: I don't know enough to say.